# Next JS, React have child component tell parent what to render

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I am new to NextJS and React and want to create some dynamic routing. I have a parent page that is calling a child component which show some navigation.

In my parent component I have a layout that includes a header and right sidebar which will show on each page, but depending on the link that is clicked in my Nav component the body content will change.

My parent component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Header } from './Header;
import { SubNav } from './SubNav;
import { Sidebar } from './Sidebar;

export const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <SubNav />

      <div className="content">
        >>>I want to do something like this <<<
        {section === history && <History />}
        {section === contact && <Contact />}
          .....
      </div>

      <Sidebar />
    </>
  );
};
```

In my child Nav component I am mapping through some data that includes a 'value' for each different section that I have defined in an array.

```
<NavButtons
  onClick={() => {
    const path = AppRoute.ABOUT.replace(':section', 'value');
    router.push(path, path, { shallow: true });
  }}
/>
```

The page routes correctly with the value of the section changing each time I click on a different Navigation button but I can't get the content to change in the parent component, I have tried creating a function in the parent that will get the value from the child so that I can use it to define the sections in the parent, but it ends up creating an infinite loop. Confused on how to get the two to work together.

Comment: use a state library. Like redux (a bit of overkill).  may be zustand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        import React from 'react';
        import {useState} from 'react';
        import { Header } from './Header';
        import { SubNav } from './SubNav';
        import { Sidebar } from './Sidebar';
        
        export const AboutPage = () => {
            const [section,setSection] = useState()
            sectionHandler = (section) => {
             setSection(section)
            }
          return (
            <>
              <Header />
              <SubNav />
        
              <div className="content">
                >>>I want to do something like this <<<
                {section === history && <History />}
                {section === contact && <Contact />}
                  .....
              </div>
        
              <Sidebar />
            </>
          );
        };
```

and in your child comp

```
     <NavButtons
      onClick={() => {
        const path = AppRoute.ABOUT.replace(':section', 'value');
        props.sectionHandler(section)
        router.push(path, path, { shallow: true });
      }}
     />
```

don't forget to pass sectionhandler from parent to child comp

Comment: I ended up implementing this with {useState} and worked great, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the pathname with the `useRouter` Hook.
Then you can check in a switch case statement which site the user is on and render the components for the route.

```
import { useRouter } from next/router
```

Inside the component

```
const router = useRouter();
```

The function to return the component

```
function renderSidebar(pathname){
switch(pathname){
...
}
```

Inside the render function

```
{ renderSidebar(router.pathname) }
```

See further usage in the NextJS docs
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router